# How to do a OR operation query in nodejs/MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, nosql

I am trying to query my `mongodb` but I don't know which row my data is under so i am trying to querying both rows with parameters, is this syntax correct?

```
db.table.find({groupA: data} || {groupB: data}, function(err, records)
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Make use of the [$or](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) operator.

```
db.table.find({$or:[{"groupA":data},{"groupB":data}]}, function(err,data){
})
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the [$or operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) in your query:

```
 db.table.find({$or:[{"groupA": data}, {"groupB": data}]}, 
     function(err, records){
      //code to be executed.
     });
```